# ErrorException Undefined variable when trying to show data in view

Tags: php, laravel

So i was trying to display a record from a database with laravel, and i have defined the variable in `@foreach` statement but when i run it it shows `ErrorException Undefined variable` , although all variable already inside the foreach statement, am i missing a method function in my controller?

this is the view
welcome.blade.php

```
<div class="blog-item">       
                        <div class="blog-text text-box text-white">
                            @foreach ($guestbooks as $guestbook)    
                            <div class="top-meta">{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($guestbook->created_at)->format('d-m-Y')  }} /  di <a href="">Rakitan</a></div>
                            <h3>{{ $guestbooks->name }}</h3>
                            <p>{!! \Illuminate\Support\Str::words($guestbook->message, 50, '...') !!}</p>
                            <a href="{{ route('post.read', ['post_id' => $post->id]) }}" class="read-more">Lanjutkan Baca  <img src="asset/img/icons/double-arrow.png" alt="#"/></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Blog item -->
                    <div class="blog-item">       
                        <div class="blog-text text-box text-white">   
                            <div class="top-meta">{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($guestbook->created_at)->format('d-m-Y')  }} /  di <a href="">Rakitan</a></div>
                            <h3>{{ $guestbook->name }}</h3>
                            <p>{!! \Illuminate\Support\Str::words($guestbook->message, 50, '...') !!}</p>
                            <a href="{{ route('post.read', ['post_id' => $post->id]) }}" class="read-more">Lanjutkan Baca  <img src="asset/img/icons/double-arrow.png" alt="#"/></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Blog item -->
                    <div class="blog-item">       
                        <div class="blog-text text-box text-white">   
                            <div class="top-meta">{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($guestbook->created_at)->format('d-m-Y')  }} /  di <a href="">Rakitan</a></div>
                            <h3>{{ $guestbook->name }}</h3>
                            <p>{!! \Illuminate\Support\Str::words($guestbook->message, 50, '...') !!}</p>
                            <a href="{{ route('post.read', ['post_id' => $post->id]) }}" class="read-more">Lanjutkan Baca  <img src="asset/img/icons/double-arrow.png" alt="#"/></a>
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

this is the controller
GuestbookController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Guestbook;

class GuestbookController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $guestbooks = Guestbook::get();
        return view('post.post_textarea',[
            'guestbooks' => $guestbooks
        ]);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        Guestbook::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'message' => $request->message
        ]);
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

and this is the routes

```
Route::get('/posting','GuestbookController@index')->name('guestbook');
Route::post('/posting','GuestbookController@store')->name('guestbook.store');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `GuestbookController` function `index()` is returning a view called `post.post_textarea` and passing your $guestbook variable to that view, while you are trying to get that variable in your `welcome.blade.php`.

Change your index function to return welcome view like this:

```
public function index()
    {
        $guestbooks = Guestbook::get();
        return view('welcome',[
            'guestbooks' => $guestbooks
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: i tried that but still getting the same error, the variable that's undefined is ```$guestbooks```

Comment: I noticed also that you used `$guestbooks->name` in your view right after foreach. Try changing that to `$guestbook->name`. As I can see it's probably a typo since your other variables are fine.

Answer (score 0):

i figured the problem was that there are two routes routing into the same url as `Route::get('/posting','GuestbookController@index')->name('guestbook');` so i delete the other one and it works thanks about that typo tough @Denis Ćerić